# Pygame Can't Set Volume to 0

Tags: python, pygame

I can't seem to set the volume of a channel to 0 in one ear. (I initiated the mixer with stereo). I did `pygame.mixer.Channel(channel).set_volume(0,volume)` and it seems to play at about half-ish volume on the left and full volume on the right. Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on windows?

The problem is not in Python or Pygame itself, but rather in Windows. It seems sound enhancements are somehow fiddling with the way the sound my script is playing (or any other Pygame script for that matter).

I'm on Windows 10 and this is how I did it:

1.Right click on the speaker icon in the taskbar

2.Select Playback Devices

3.Select Speakers and Properties

4.Go to Enhancements tab and uncheck Equalizer and Loudness Equalization

That's it.

Comment: There is no enhancements tab. I looked it up and supposedly that means my audio playback device is not capable of enhancements, so shouldn't it not be able to equalize it?

Comment: Are you on windows and what audio playback device?

Comment: Yes, windows 10.

Comment: You may need admin privalages to access the Enchantments.